# an in-code keyword for linking a .lib file

Tags: c++, c, linker, linkage

I'm using `VS2010` to write some `win32` app. I normally add .lib files to linkage using to project property manager. yet, sometimes, when I just want to test an API function , I don't want to modify my project file , but rather just add a removable line for linking with the required lib

What is the linker keyword for linking with a given `.lib` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `#pragma comment` command

Example:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")
```

Another example:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "yourlibrary.lib")
```

Just put in hmm.. before `int main(){}`

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153901

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

If there are problems:

[Ignore #pragma comment(lib, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860109/ignore-pragma-commentlib?rq=1)

[Unresolved external symbol when linking my library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737017/unresolved-external-symbol-when-linking-my-library)

Comment: it's what I was looking for, yet the linker is yelling at me for `unresolved symbols`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737017/unresolved-external-symbol-when-linking-my-library :)

Comment: thanks, but it's the correct lib and no typos. I actually copied the name from the `#pragma` statement to the vs project manager and it worked.

Comment: `V` anyways as it was the keyword I was looking for.